# what is the equivalent to PostgereSQL's "ip <<"?

Tags: mysql, ip-address, cidr

I have a large number of bind9 queries entered with a Perl Script into a simple
MySQL table, where the IP address is an integer which I can `SELECT` with

`INET_NTOA(167772161) = '10.01.1.1'`

I want to select addresses falling into a a particular CIDR Block like I can do
in PostgreSQL with something like

`WHERE IP << '10.0.0.0/16'"`.

Now what I want is to find all addresses in the table that fall within for example `10.0.0.0/8` or whatever network block.

Any ideas?

greetings, el

Comment: As MySQL does not have a native data type for IP addresses, I'd say there is no equivalent to that operator. You will need write your own stored function for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bit shift operators in MySQL. Just a bit more work:

```
select 167772169 >> 16, inet_aton('10.0.0.0') >> 16
```

returns the same integer of the network address (shifted 16 bits to the right).